# Trying to correctly use the copy and paste functions in vba

Tags: vba, copy

Im trying to take the data from PA_Model and save in a workbook im calling Multiple_Inforce_Files.  This should be saved in a new worksheet that is named respective to Inforce_Data which is defined earlier. The macro is opening the workbook and creating the worksheet with the correct name, but its not pasting the PA_Model.  Its actually pasting the last thing that I copied from my computer

```
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("PA_Model").Range("a1").CurrentRegion
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("PA_Model").Copy

wb_new.Activate
Worksheets.Add.Name = New_Inforce & "_" & "Data"
Worksheets(New_Inforce & "_" & "Data").Select


ActiveSheet.Paste
```

Answer (score 0):

No need for activate

```vb
Dim newWs as worksheet

set newWs = wb_new.Worksheets.Add() 'add the sheet first
newWs.Name = New_Inforce & "_Data"

ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("PA_Model").Range("a1").Copy newWs.Range("A1")
```